# How can I completely hide a directory in .net vb

Tags: vb.net

I can do this using command prompt **attrib +s +h c:\stock** and the directory will be totally hidden from file explorer.

If however I do it in code like below it will show up the directory if view hidden files is ticked. Can someone tell me how in code i could achieve a total hide of a directory like what the **attrib** command does.

Below is my code :-

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        IO.File.SetAttributes("c:\stock", IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent VB.NET of **attrib +s +h** is

```
IO.File.SetAttributes("c:\stock", IO.FileAttributes.Hidden  Or 
                                  IO.FileAttributes.System)
```

(+s is System attribute)

but you have not really made your directory totally hidden because the visualization of System files and directory could be enabled as you enable the visualization of Hidden files and directory.

[Make a Super Hidden Folder in Windows Without any Extra Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/104825/make-a-super-hidden-folder-in-windows-without-any-extra-software/)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @BASitBulbulia If it works, then The Right Thing to do is to click the checkmark

Comment: @Plutonix . . . indeed ! !  thanks for the reminder . . .

Comment: @Plutonix - just got to let you know that I got the checkmark to work after many attempts - each time I got a red box with white writing in it stating" An error has occured - please retry your request"